# ¿Cómo prevenir que Excel cambie el formato de los números al transformar a columnas?

Tags: excel, formato

Tengo un archivo CSV el cual está compuesto por miles de filas y una única columna que contiene varios valores, todos juntos en la única columna, separados por coma.

Los valores son cotizaciones de bolsa, por lo que se trata de números aleatorios en su gran mayoría en formato 1.000000.

Al transformar los datos en columnas, Excel automáticamente convierte los valores de cotización, del formato original 1.000000 a 1.000.000

¿Cómo puedo prevenir que Excel cambie el formato de los valores de cotización?

La transformación la realizo mediante la pestaña 'Datos' y la opción 'Texto en columnas' en Excel 2016.

Comment: La carga del CSV desde donde la haces?!

Comment: Desde el propio excel. Es un fichero que me ha pasado un compañero que desconozco de dónde lo ha sacado. Pero para abrirlo selecciono el archivo en la carpeta que lo tengo. No sé si te refieres a esa pregunta o a otra. En caso de que no haya contestado a tu pregunta, detállala de otra manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la parte donde especificas el tipo de dato que importa el CSV, usa **texto**, con ello se importará como tal. Si lo dejas en General, excel lo transformará al formato por defecto que tengas, con separadores de miles (asumo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: En el asistente te muestra que como General, "conservará" el formato pero al finalizar caerás en cuenta que no. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto! Me sirvio!
El fallo que estaba cometiendo es que desconocía que tenía que especificar el formato EN CADA COLUMNA. Ahora que lo he hecho en cada columna, da el resultado que buscaba.
Gracias!

Comment: De nada, son cosas que a veces se nos pasan. No olvides marcar la respuesta como la que te sirvio. Gracias !

Comment: Marcada ! gracias!